# Sitecore 10.1 standalone instance always brings 0 interactions

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I've tried this code, taken almost directly from Sitecore documentation (they are using Goal, I'm using PageViewEvent).

```
var itemId = <some id of an Item in content>;
using (var client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
{
  queryable = client.Interactions.Where(x =>
    x.Events.OfType<Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.PageViewEvent>().Any(y =>
      y.ItemId == itemId.Guid));
                 

  if (queryable == null) return totalCount;

  Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Synchronous.IEntityBatchEnumerator<Interaction> enumerable = 
    queryable.GetBatchEnumeratorSync();

  while (enumerable.MoveNext())
  {
    foreach (Interaction interaction in enumerable.Current)
    {
      int pageVisits = interaction.Events.OfType<Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.PageViewEvent>().Count(x =>
        x.ItemId == itemId.Guid &&
        x.ItemLanguage == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name);

      if (uniqueVisits)
      {
        pageVisits = pageVisits > 0 ? 1 : 0;
      }

      totalCount += pageVisits;
    }
  }
}
```

This always 0 returns for `totalCount`. On closer inspection, I found that the actual *interactions* are 0 (i.e. `client.Interactions` even without filtering, returns a `totalCount` of 0).

I check the analytics reports and I see page visits, even to the particular item I'm using, so it appears that data exists.

Any idea why this is happening, and/or what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`client.Interactions` uses `xDB` indexes to get the data. I recommend you to check if the [indexing of anonymous contacts](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-platform/enable-indexing-of-anonymous-contacts-in-the-xdb-index.html) is enabled or if there are interactions with required data for known contacts.

If the issue is still reproducible after that, you can check the query which is executed on `SOLR` when you run your code:

https://spl-tricks.github.io/2019/09/07/SOLRQueryReplaying/

Comment: I came across this same issue myself and it was as @SPLs suggested - annonymous contacts in the index

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
IAsyncQueryable<Interaction> queryable = client.Interactions
    .Where(x => x.Events.Any(y => y.DefinitionId == Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.PageViewEvent.EventDefinitionId))
    //.WithExpandOptions(new InteractionExpandOptions(new string[] { IpInfo.DefaultFacetKey })
    //{
        //Contact = new RelatedContactExpandOptions(TrialFacet.DefaultFacetKey)
    //});

var enumerable = queryable.GetBatchEnumeratorSync(200);
```

I added the contact facet code (remmed out) just in case you need to get contact Facets also.

Comment: Hello Chris. I don't see how this will help me. As stated, client.Interactions returns 0 results, so your code will also return 0 results (it's a "Where" clause on a collection with 0 results). Unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: I have always had trouble with the OfType<> searches. Mine goes off it DefinitionId. Works better for me.

Comment: I can understand that, but my issue is not on the where clause. My issue is that the following:
 using (var client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
            {
                queryable = client.Interactions
           }

returns an empty set, ie it appears as though there are no interactions (while clearly there are, because they appear within sitecore analytics)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `user interaction (either event or goal)` before submitting the contact to XDB.

I am writing below a sample code to save interaction:

```
public virtual ContactIdentifier CreateContact(string email, PersonalInformation personalInfo)
    {
        var identifier = new ContactIdentifier(ContactSource, email, ContactIdentifierType.Known);
        var identifiers = new ContactIdentifier[] { identifier };

        try
        {
            if (CurrentTracker != null && CurrentTracker.IsActive && CurrentTracker.Session != null)
            {
                CurrentTracker.Session.IdentifyAs(ContactSource, email);
                CurrentTracker.Contact.Tags.Set("isEmpty", "false");
            }

            using (var client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
            {
                var knownContact = new Contact(identifiers);
                client.SetFacet(knownContact, PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey, personalInfo);
                client.AddContact(knownContact);

                // Add User interaction before submit contact
                Guid channelId = Guid.Parse("27A7E0C2-DE17-46C8-8AA3-CFEC0434CCEB");
                var interaction = new Sitecore.XConnect.Interaction(knownContact, InteractionInitiator.Brand, channelId, "userAgent");
                var fakeItemID = Guid.Parse("1D5C266A-112F-4EA2-A69E-E4865ACE2200"); // Replace with real item ID
                PageViewEvent pageView = new PageViewEvent(DateTime.UtcNow, fakeItemID, 3, "en")
                {
                    Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30),
                    Url = "/Home"
                };
                interaction.Events.Add(pageView);
                client.AddInteraction(interaction);

                client.Submit();
            }
        }
        catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Exception creating contact", ex, this);
        }
        return identifier;
    }
```

Comment: Hello Himmat. I'm not trying to register an interaction, I'm only trying to retrieve the number of pageview events for a specific page. The ultimate goal is to get the "most popular" pages.